# How to modify subject of Elmah emailing when using WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, elmah

Normally in my Mvc project, I simply have a ErrorMail_Mailing method in Global.asax.cs which gives access to ErrorMailEventArgs.

But in WebApi, this method does not fire, so how can I access this information in Webapi?

I am currently using this methodology (which is working fine)

```
public class ApiErrorHandler : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            DepResolver.ExceptionHelper().LogToElmah(context.Exception);
            base.OnException(context);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELMAH doesn't fire on Web API by default. You need to either catch the error yourself and log it to ELMAH or even better, use the Elmah.Contrib.WebApi NuGet package: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.Contrib.WebApi/. With that package installed, simply add the following code to your Application_Start:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ElmahHandleErrorApiAttribute());
```

This should trigger that your ErrorMail_Mailing method is called.